# Como adaptar el viewport width de una pantalla movil a las dimensiones de la pantalla

Tags: html, css

- Buenas, estaba haciendo una pagina que me interesa que pueda ser vista desde moviles tambien, sin embargo, tengo un problema. El `viewport width` y el `viewport height` no esta siendo igual a la resolucion de la pantalla del movil sino un poco mas grande. Se supone que la etiqueta `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />` hace que precisamente no pase eso, pero en mi caso no esta funcionando, que puedo hacer??

Comment: Puede ser que tengas un conflicto en tu `CSS`, pero para estar seguros, necesitamos que nos compartas el código necesario para revisar.

Comment: Este error aparece generalmente por un problema de padding y margin. Debes revisarlos

Answer (score 0):

Puede que el viewport sea mayor porque se permite el zoom y quizá esté activado el zoom. Si añades maximum-scale=1 evitarás que el usuario pueda hacer zoom.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).